# Can you eliminate rows in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My matrix:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 4 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &-1 & 3 & 3 \\
    0 &-4 & 0 & 0 &-8 \\
    0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
Can I use the row operation `R3 + R4` or `R4 + R3` to remove a row, or is it illegal to have a row with all `0`'s?

Comment: It is not a problem. It means that row is in the span of the rows above it. (Watch out for the row operation police, though.)

Comment: Each row represents some data in space, so when you can reduce one row using another row, it means that they both were representing data in same direction and you can remove either one of them and scale the other to achieve its result.So, each row shall point in unique direction. When saying they are representing each other includes all vector properties to represent each other.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, @Blackbird. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a two rows of vectors where one is a scalar multiple of another then the rows are linearly dependent and you can remove either row.

Comment: Am I left with a row full of 0's or do I just completely remove the row from the matrix?

Comment: For the example you gave above do as you said and R3+R4 you will have a row of zeros in the last row.

Comment: One more question, not worth making another thread. Can you multiply a row by -1?

Comment: @Xzar: Row of zero means you are sitting at center/origin which belong to every matrix unless specified explicitly.If it its possible to exclude, though it doesn't make sense because point of reference will be gone/shifted.

Comment: Yes, you can muliply a row by -1.